# Getting error in android spinner in marshmallow

Tags: android, filter, textview, android-spinner

I have used spinner to fetch all the schoolnames from database. as well as textbox to filter the schoolnames.It works well in all android versions except in android 6.o.
  When i run the program in android 6.0 i am getting the following error:

Error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pencilrulernidhinkumar.pencilruler/pencilrulernidhinkumar.pencilruler.PupilRegi}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4098)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1360)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference
>       at pencilrulernidhinkumar.pencilruler.PupilRegi$5.onTextChanged(PupilRegi.java:189)
>       at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7998)
>       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4355)
>       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4209)
>       at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:84)
>       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4184)
>       at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:4077)
>       at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:14768)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3129)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3129)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3129)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3129)
>       at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:14746)
>       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2035)
>       at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1012)
>       at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:967)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1186)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2399)

Here is my Class file to load the school names and filter it.

```
public class PupilRegi extends Activity{
private static final String PREF_FIRSTLAUNCH_HELP = "helppupilregister";
private boolean helpDisplayed = false;
EditText pupilname,pupusername,puppassword,codezip,schoolsearch;
TextView pupdob,imagepath;
Spinner pupyear,pupschool;
Button submit;
ResultSet rs;
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
ConnectionDetector cd;
AlertDialog alert;
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter;
ConnectionClass connectionClass;
String orig,names,imagename,imgpath;
private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private Uri fileUri;
static final int DATE_PICKER_ID = 1111;
public static final String USER_NAME = "USER_NAME";
public static final String PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://balajee2777-001-site1.1tempurl.com/backup-07032016/studentregister.php";
private String URL_CATEGORIES = "http://balajee2777-001-site1.1tempurl.com/backup-07032016/spinnerdb/get_categories.php";
private String URL_SCHOOL = "http://balajee2777-001-site1.1tempurl.com/backup-07032016/spinnerdb/school.php";

public static Bitmap bitmap;
private ArrayList<Category> categoriesList;
private ArrayList<Categories> categoriesSchool;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.student);
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
    showHelpForFirstLaunch();
    schoolsearch=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    pupyear=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.regpupilyear);
    pupschool=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.regschoolname);
    pupilname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.rdtextpupilname);
    pupdob=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.regeddob);
    imagepath=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.reggtvimagepath);
    pupusername=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.regedusername);
    puppassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.regedpassword);
    codezip=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edzipcode);
    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsubmitreg);
    connectionClass= new ConnectionClass();
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    categoriesList = new ArrayList<Category>();
    categoriesSchool=new ArrayList<Categories>();
    pupdob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);
        }
    });
    if(isInternetPresent){
        new Getyear().execute();
        new Getschool().execute();

    }else{
        neti();
    }
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isInternetPresent) {
                login();
            }else{
                neti();
            }

        }
    });
    schools();
}

private void showHelpForFirstLaunch() {
    helpDisplayed = getPreferenceValue(PREF_FIRSTLAUNCH_HELP, false);
    if (!helpDisplayed) {
        showHelp();
        savePreference(PREF_FIRSTLAUNCH_HELP, true);
    }else if(helpDisplayed){
        return;
    }


}
private void showHelp() {
    final View instructionsContainer = findViewById(R.id.container_help);
    instructionsContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    instructionsContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            instructionsContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
private boolean getPreferenceValue(String key, boolean defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
}

private void savePreference(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

private void neti() {
    final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(PupilRegi.this);
    final View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.connectionlost, null);
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PupilRegi.this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    final Button retry=(Button)promptView.findViewById(R.id.btnretry);
    retry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    alert= alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
}

private void schools() {
    schoolsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           PupilRegi.this.spinnerAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}

private void login() {
    String imgepath=codezip.getText().toString();
    String name=pupilname.getText().toString();
    String dob=pupdob.getText().toString();
    String school=pupschool.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String year=pupyear.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String username = pupusername.getText().toString();
    String password = puppassword.getText().toString();
    if(name.isEmpty() && username.isEmpty() && imgepath.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(PupilRegi.this, "Enter all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if(name.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(PupilRegi.this, "Enter Yourname", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if(username.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(PupilRegi.this,"Enter username",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if(password.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(PupilRegi.this, "Enter password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if(imgepath.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(PupilRegi.this, "Enter ZipCode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        userLogin(name,dob,school,year,imgepath,username, password);
    }
}
private void userLogin(String name,String dob,String school,String year,String imgepath, final String username, final String password) {
    class UserLoginClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(PupilRegi.this, "Wait a while!", null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            // pb1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE
            Intent intent = new Intent(PupilRegi.this, SqlLogin.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            // intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, username);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();



        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("name",params[0]);
            data.put("dob",params[1]);
            data.put("school",params[2]);
            data.put("year",params[3]);
            data.put("imgepath",params[4]);
            data.put("username",params[5]);
            data.put("password",params[6]);
            RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();
            String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(LOGIN_URL,data);
            return result;
        }
    }
    UserLoginClass ulc = new UserLoginClass();
    ulc.execute(name,dob,school,year,imgepath,username,password);
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_PICKER_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month,day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                          int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

        year  = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day   = selectedDay;

        // Show selected date
        pupdob.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day)
                .append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(year)
                .append(" "));

    }
};


private class Getyear extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
       // pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
       // pDialog.setMessage("Fetching food categories..");
       // pDialog.setCancelable(false);
       // pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
        String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_CATEGORIES, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    JSONArray categories = jsonObj
                            .getJSONArray("categories");

                    for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) categories.get(i);
                        Category cat = new Category(catObj.getString("Grade"));
                        categoriesList.add(cat);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
       // if (pDialog.isShowing())
        //    pDialog.dismiss();
        populateSpinner();
    }

}

private void populateSpinner() {
    List<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();

    //txtCategory.setText("");

    for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {
        lables.add(categoriesList.get(i).getName());
    }

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables){
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(SingleItem.sTypeFace(getApplicationContext()));//Typeface for normal view

            return v;
        }
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(SingleItem.sTypeFace(getApplicationContext()));//Typeface for dropdown view
            ((TextView)v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            // ((TextView)v).setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
            ((TextView) v).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c13d48"));
            return v;
        }
    };

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    spinnerAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    pupyear.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
}




private class Getschool extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // pDialog.setMessage("Fetching food categories..");
        // pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
        String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_SCHOOL, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

        if (json != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    JSONArray school = jsonObj
                            .getJSONArray("school");

                    for (int i = 0; i < school.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) school.get(i);
                        Categories catz = new Categories(catObj.getString("School_Name"));
                        categoriesSchool.add(catz);
                    }
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // if (pDialog.isShowing())
        //    pDialog.dismiss();
        populateSchool();
    }


}

private void populateSchool() {
    List<String> labls = new ArrayList<String>();

    //txtCategory.setText("");

    for (int i = 0; i < categoriesSchool.size(); i++) {
        labls.add(categoriesSchool.get(i).getName());
    }

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labls){
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(SingleItem.sTypeFace(getApplicationContext()));//Typeface for normal view

            return v;
        }
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(SingleItem.sTypeFace(getApplicationContext()));//Typeface for dropdown view
            ((TextView)v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            // ((TextView)v).setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
            ((TextView) v).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c13d48"));
            return v;
        }
    };

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    spinnerAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    pupschool.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a spinnerAdapter locally on populateSpinner function, also another mistake I noticed is when you don't have internet it seems you don't want to run the async task on which you create the spinnerAdapter (onPostExecute), so when you will try to enter something on schoolsearch field you will get null pointer exception, before you starting the task and even check if there is a network connection available, allocate the adapter with empty set of values.

Comment: allocate spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new ArrayList<String>());
after setContent in onCreate

Answer (score 0):

SpinnerFilterActivity.java

```
public class SpinnerFilterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
private ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;
private Spinner mTestSPN;
private ArrayList<String> mSpinnerArray;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSpinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    mSpinnerArray.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_name)));
    mTestSPN = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_test);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_test);
    mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mSpinnerArray){
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            //TODO set Typeface
            // ((TextView) v).setTypeface(SingleItem.sTypeFace(getApplicationContext()));//Typeface for normal view
            return v;
        }
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            //TODO set Typeface
            //  ((TextView) v).setTypeface(SingleItem.sTypeFace(getApplicationContext()));//Typeface for dropdown view
            ((TextView)v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            // ((TextView)v).setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
            ((TextView) v).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c13d48"));
            return v;
        }
    };
    mTestSPN.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                mArrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.btn_test).setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void populateSpinner() {
    mSpinnerArray.add("new data 1");
    mSpinnerArray.add("new data 2");
    mSpinnerArray.add("filter data");
    mSpinnerArray.add("new filter");
    mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mSpinnerArray){
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            //TODO set Typeface
            //  ((TextView) v).setTypeface(SingleItem.sTypeFace(getApplicationContext()));//Typeface for normal view
            return v;
        }
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            //TODO set Typeface
            // ((TextView) v).setTypeface(SingleItem.sTypeFace(getApplicationContext()));//Typeface for dropdown view
            ((TextView)v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            // ((TextView)v).setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
            ((TextView) v).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c13d48"));
            return v;
        }
    };
    mTestSPN.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 if(v.getId()==R.id.btn_test){
    populateSpinner();
 }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="#f4f4f4" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/spn_test"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<string-array name="array_name">
    <item>Array Item One</item>
    <item>Array Item Two</item>
    <item>Array Item Three</item>
    <item>Array Item Four</item>
    <item>Array Item Five</item>
</string-array>
```

This is sample code with array adapter with filter feature. You can change the code according to your need.

As per your code error you just need to do the initialization of spinnerAdapter at the very beginning and whenever data got change at run time add the new data in list and notify your adapter. I have added the code snippet.